# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\cos(nx)| \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis

I hope this should be fairly straightforward. Does anyone have any advice to offer on evaluating the limit 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\cos(nx)| \mathrm{d}x
$$
which, I've been led to believe, is zero? I'm still fairly new at working with the $L^2$ integral norm, so I lack a repertoire of ideas for how to evaluate integrals of this general type.

P.S. I couldn't find it, but did I overlook an earlier posting of the same question?

Thanks.

Comment: However, it is not zero:
$$
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\cos(nx)| \mathrm{d}x \ge   \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2(nx) \mathrm{d}x=\frac12\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1+ \cos(2nx)) \mathrm{d}x=\pi
$$

Comment: Anyway, $|\cos t|\ge cos^2t $ for any $t$, since $ |\cos t|\le 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To evaluate : $$
 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\cos(nx)| \mathrm{d}x
$$

Put $nx=t$ and then we get integral transformed to :

$$\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi} |\cos(t)| \mathrm{d}t
$$

$$=\frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^{n\pi} |\cos(t)| \mathrm{d}t
$$

But as $$\int_{0}^{\pi} |\cos(t)| \mathrm{d}t=2$$ and cosine is periodic, we get :

$=\frac{2}{n}\left(2n\right)=4$

So the limit is $4$, not zero.

Comment: Beautiful, and very succinct! How strange that this crazy function just converges to a constant w.r.t. an integral norm.

Comment: *this crazy sequence of functions, I should say